# Three words with three animals

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, no-computers, animals

Can you give me at least 3 ( I found 4 so far) *Five Letter words* with at least 3 animal names spelled in them? No anagrams (rearranging letters).

The 3 animal names must be in ONE WORD. Find 3 seperate words like that

For example the word BEARD has only one animal name Bear in it.

One word I found had 4 animal names spelled in it.

No computers please. Any standard dictionary (including Wiktionary) words are fine. Please no partial answers.

Comment: Do you mean 3 animal names in *each word*? And if so, does the 'hen' in 'hyena' count or do the letters have to be sequential?

Comment: are we to assume continuous letters and forward only?

Comment: Yes 3 animal names in ONE WORD

Comment: How are we supposed to find such words without computers (wordfind etc)?

Comment: Oray. Logically one can think of animal names that are kind of matching.

Comment: JonMark Forward only. Continuous not necessary. So say a Pig can be spelled as first third and last letter P_I_G

Comment: does BEELK count? (its Swiss)

Comment: May be JonMark but there are english words

Comment: Oray  The one answer with one animal name only (now deleted) actually had one answer in it with 2 may be 3 animals

Comment: @DeepakMahulikar ai and ox are the only animals with 2 letters it seems. you mean foxed? fox, ox and?

Comment: tit, titi, titis? :)

Comment: Oray  Think about Owl

Comment: scowl -> sow (female pig), cow (female cow), owl (bird)

Comment: JonMark, yup. The real challenge for me was to find a word with 4 animal names

Comment: Stop posting these comments:  [edit] your question to have the ***complete*** rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to

> SCOWL

From Oray's deleted post, I found 3 more. Two contain 3 animal names and one contains 4.

> COATI, a South American animal that also contains:
> C-AT-  (Cat)
> --A-I (Ai, a type of sloth)
>
> ASPIS (ancient shield) contains:
> ASP-- (Asp, a snake)
> A--I- (Ai, a type of sloth)
> AS--S (Ass, a donkey)
>
> KRAIT (a type of snake) also contains:
> -RA-T (Rat)
> --AI- (Ai, a type of sloth)
> K--IT (Kit, short for kitten)

**EDIT:** Found another one with 4 animal names:

> BRANT (a type of goose) also contains:
>  B-A-T (Bat)
>  -RA-T (Rat)
>  --ANT (Ant)

And another one that contains 3 or 4 animal names:

> BOART (variant spelling of bort, a low-quality diamond) contains:
>  B-A-T (Bat)
>  BOA-- (Boa, a snake)
>  BOAR- (Boar, a wild pig)
>  BO--T (Bot, the larva of the botfly)
>
>  And if 'bot' counts, there are other words (like 'boast') that contain 3.

As for a simple one,

> CROWD contains:
>  CROW-
>  C-OW-
>  C-O-D
>
> [There's also 'scrow' (crow-cow-sow), but it's obsolete]

Comment: Only 2 words with 3 animal names Walt. But good start. Now if you find that 1 word with 4 animal names-------

Comment: Sorry.Walt. I thought SCOWL was already answered. My Bad

Comment: Again my bad. you have the 3

Comment: Walt. Missing 2 from my answer. One very simple

Comment: @DeepakMahulikar Added a simpler one. Is that one of them?

Comment: CROWD  probably the simplest

Answer (score 2):

Maybe that four words in one:

> BRANT

which is

> BRANT - A species of wild goose
>  BAT
>  RAT
>  ANT

and some other:

> CROWD
>  COW
>  CROW
>  COD - fish

Comment: Came to the same conclusion only half a minute prior. :O But +1 anyway. There are probably others with those shorter ones (& 'cat').

Answer (score 0):

I have one

> BLOAT

Which has

> BOA
>  BAT
>  BOT

and one more

> BREEL - A strange sinuous eel like creature

has

> BEE, EEL and BREEL itself

Comment: Did you miss `No anagrams (rearranging letters).` in the OP?

Comment: No, @Mithrandir, there was no rearrangement there !

Comment: Yes there was - the example was in, say, the word 'bear' in 'beard'. The word 'boa' is not in 'bloat' - you ignore an `L` that way. (Also, how is BOT an animal?)

Comment: @Mithrandir OP said that continuous letters aren't necessay. Please read the comments to the question.

Comment: @Walt - ugh. That should probably be edited into the original question >.<

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay Well, I mentioned the first one's structure in my answer, and I'm afraid the 2nd one is not a real word. It can only be found on UrbanDictionary, which often makes stuff up. It's a joke entry there.

Answer (score -1):

wHEN COWard CROWd GO-AT FISHin.

More than 3 five letter words with more than 3 animal names spelled in them.

Comment: Each of the three words must have three animals.